# Google Shopping Product Expiration Date is not updated

Tags: magento-1.8

I have implement [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html) extension and its working good except one thing. 
Products expiration date field for Google shopping is not updated while synchronizing.

I have Google a lot and found out that we need to delete and re upload all the product again which are expired, which i thing is not a good solution( Since Google takes a lot of time to review any new product)

On debugging i found that

```
<sc:expiration_date>2014-08-13T14:37:22.000-07:00</sc:expiration_date>
```

this is always sent to Google while adding or synchronizing product, but while synchronizing the value of this field is not updated and hence product expires in 30 days on Google merchant.

Is this a know issue ?
Has any faced this issue?If yes, then how it can be solved.

Thank You

Comment: You can search for this attribute in the extension code and replace 30 days with, say 60.

Comment: I did and but was not helpful

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you are using is very much outdated.

**Solution:**
You need to remove the Expiration date feed completely so that Google can assign it its own date (it assigns a default date if this is missing), which you can set it up in Google merchant centre

Else, just increase the date to 30 days (max value that Google can support).

Google does NOT re-evaluate a produce once it is approved by Google merchant.